# migrate через файл php (YII)

Tags: php, yii, миграция

есть задача реализовать миграции через файл install подскажите можно ли запустить миграции не через консоль а через файл php ?

к примеру если через фреймворк  я запускаю миграции через консоль  пишу  "yii migatre" подтверждаю "yes" и выполняются миграции , но как сделать чтобы миграции запустились автоматически в файле php . к примеру делал так

```
__DIR__.'/yii.php migrate';
```

но ничего не происходит как правильно реализовать если это возможно ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   class MigrateController
{
    public function Up()
    {
        ob_start();
        $oldApp = \Yii::$app;
        $runner = new \yii\console\Application([
            'id'            => 'Command runner',
            'basePath'      => __DIR__ . '/../../',
            'components'    => [
                'db' => $oldApp->db,
            ],
        ]);

        @$runner->runAction('migrate/up', ['migrationPath' => __DIR__ . '/../migrations', 'interactive' => false]);
        @Yii::$app = $oldApp;
        return ob_get_clean();

    }
}
```